# Which JavaScript library you recommend to use with Java EE + Struts + iBatis?

Tags: java, javascript, struts, javascript-framework

Which JavaScript library you recommend to use with Java EE + Struts + iBatis ?
Something like Ext JS, Dojo, frameworks that can be easily integrated with Struts.

Comment: What are you using the JS library for?  Do you need widgets and advanced UI components?  What are your licensing restrictions?

Comment: I need JS for display enhancements, and I need free libraries

Answer (score 2):

There exists a framework that is supposed to tie in nicely with Java Server/Middleware called [JSON-RPC](http://oss.metaparadigm.com/jsonrpc/)

However I have never used it and cannot vouch for it.. Aside from that my favourite framework is *cough* [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

**edit** after reading more closely, the JSON-RPC is not quite what you are looking for.. but it still might be useful for ya to look into ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article on [Dojo for Java Developers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-dojo/index.html?ca=dgr-lnxw16wa-aj-dojo&S_TACT=105AGX59&S_CMP=GRsitelnxw16).

Comment: Some more recent: http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/06/dojo-json-rpc-java/ AND http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/01/03/many-comet-solutions-for-your-real-time-apps/

Answer (score 2):

You must choose the Javascript library based on what you expect from the library, not based on the server libraries. The tipical JS libraries (Ext JS, JQuery, Prototype, Dojo, YUI, etc) work on the browser and don't have any dependence on server tecnology.

If you are looking for a way to use your server POJO's from javascript take a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/). This library is now part of the dojo foundation, but I've used it with jQuery and Prototype with ease.

Answer (score 0):

would suggest you go for Struts 2. It has built in dojo and also has options to plugin other libraries like prototype, jquery, gwt, yui, etc.

Should be really handy, since you're using Struts as your web layer..